# How to upload a file in Email format using slack API

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am trying to post an email content to Slack. Email fileType is mentioned in the accepted FileType list for upload file API. But when I try to upload an .eml file, it gets uploaded as Binary fileType. Can someone please help with the format to be posted to get the email posted in the below format.

[image: email file]

Comment: Can you share the code that contains the file upload method.